# Unable to retrieve images from parse

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

Please help me solve my problem. I have looked everywhere to try and find a solution. Thank You for trying to help me.

This is my program to retrieve the image from parse.

```
newPicture = new pictureUpload();
ParseImageView dogPhoto2 = (ParseImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
Log.d("test", "after");
dogPhoto1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ParseFile photoFile = newPicture.getParseFile("photo");
if (photoFile != null) {
    dogPhoto1.setParseFile(photoFile);
    dogPhoto1.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            // nothing to do
            Log.d("test", "done");
        }
    });
}
```

This is my pictureUpload class.

```
@ParseClassName("pictureUpload")
public class pictureUpload extends ParseObject {

    public pictureUpload() {

    }

    public int getRating() {
        return getInt("rating");
    }

    public void setRating() {
        put("rating", 500);
    }

    public ParseFile getPhotoFile() {
        return getParseFile("photo");
    }

    public void setPhotoFile(ParseFile file) {
        put("photo", file);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not providing any way to get information from the Parse database.

```
newPicture = new pictureUpload();
ParseFile photoFile = newPicture.getParseFile("photo");
```

You need to do a query or get or something to fetch the data.  Right now you're trying to get a file from an empty ParseObject.

Comment: Check the guide, that's really basic parse.com stuff that you will need to have down to use it effectively.  It sounds like you have not read it at all, and if that's the case I recommend starting at the beginning and reading all the way through the guide. https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide